# Show that, for all $\delta < \mu(S) $, $\delta >0 $, exists a subset $T$ of $S$ such that $\mu(T) = \delta$.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $ \mu $ the lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ and let $S$ a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with $\mu(S) > 0 $.

$(a)$ Show that, for all $\delta < \mu(S) $, $\delta >0 $, exists a subset  $T$ of $S$ such that $\mu(T) = \delta. $

(We can start with S bounded)

$(b)$ For all Borel measure (a) is true?

I started from the definitions of measure (outer) Lebesgue and use union of intervals but I don't know how to proceed

Comment: The function $f(t) = \mu(S\cap[-t,t])$ is continuous

Answer (score 1):

For (b), consider the Dirac measure (point mass at the origin) as a counterexample.

For (a), consider the map

$$
F :(0,\infty), t \mapsto \mu((-t,t)\cap S).
$$

Show that $F$ is increasing and continuous with $F(t)\to \mu(S)$ as $t\to\infty$.

Why does that help you?

Comment: Since $F$ is increasing and continuos from $F(0)=0$ to $\lim_{t\to +\infty} F(t)=\mu(S)$, fixing $\delta > 0$ we can find $t'$ such that $F(t')=\delta$ e $T=(-t',t') \cap S$.
But how can I show that F is continuos?

Comment: Use that for $s\leq t$, we have $0\leq F(t)-F(s)\leq \mu ([(-t,t)\cap S]\setminus [(-s,s)\cap S])\leq \mu((-t,t)\setminus(-s,s))$. I will let you take it from there.

Comment: Perfect! thanks PhoemueX! With Dirac and $x_0=0$ measure the function F fails continuity inscreasing from 0 to 1 because it's a discrete measure; I can use whatever discrete measure